# Is there a way of creating multiple like forms on a page?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have multiple images on a page that I'm hoping to have a like button on each. Right now it works up to a point, on click it updates the database of the image you've liked and changed the image to a red heart, but 2 things happen:

1. When clicking one like button, it sets all of them off, but only the one clicked will get committed to database.
2. I can't click again to unlike.

I've tried using jQuery and Ajax, when clicking the heart/like button it will then change all the parameters with 'attr' to reflect the unlike form.

//Here is the form for the like button

```
<form class='like_form_p' name='like' action='/like.php' method='post'>
    <input type='hidden' style='display:none;' name='aid' id='aid' value='".$results['aID']."'>
    <input type='hidden' style='display:none;' name='uid' id='uid' value='".$uid."'>
    <input type='hidden' style='display:none;' name='currenturl' id='currenturl' value='".$currentURL."'>
    <input type='hidden' style='display:none;' name='pId' id='pId' value='".$cover['pId']."'>
    <input type='image' class='like_btn' src='/images/heart.png' alt='submit' width='24' height='20'>
</form>
```

//Here is the form for the unlike button

```
<form class='unlike_form_p' name='unlike' action='/unlike_cover.php' method='post'>
    <input type='hidden' style='display:none;' name='aid' id='aid' value='".$results['aID']."'>
    <input type='hidden' style='display:none;' name='uid' id='uid' value='".$uid."'>
    <input type='hidden' style='display:none;' name='currenturl' id='currenturl' value='".$currentURL."'>
    <input type='hidden' style='display:none;' name='pId' id='pId' value='".$cover['pId']."'>
    <input type='image' class='like_btn' src='/images/heart_a.png' alt='submit' width='24' height='20'>
</form>
```

//Here is the jQuery script that runs

```
<script>
function like()
{   
    $('.like_form_p').attr('action', '/unlike.php');
    $('.like_form_p').attr('class', 'unlike_form_p');
    $('.like_btn').attr('src', '/images/heart_a.png');
};
function unlike()
{
    $('.unlike_form_p').attr('action', '/like.php');
    $('.unlike_form_p').attr('class', 'like_form_p');
    $('.like_btn').attr('src', '/images/heart.png');
};

$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.like_form_p').on('submit', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var form_data = $(this).serialize();
        console.log(form_data);
        $.ajax({
            url:'/like.php',
            method:'POST',
            data:form_data,

            success:function(data)
            {   
                like()
            },
            error:function(xhr, status, error)
            {
                alert("I have failed");
            }
        })
    })
});

$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.unlike_form_p').on('submit', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var form_data = $(this).serialize();
        console.log(form_data);
        $.ajax({
            url:'/unlike.php',
            method:'POST',
            data:form_data,

            success:function(data)
            {
                unlike()
            },
            error:function(xhr, status, error)
            {
                alert("I have failed");
            }
        })
    })
});
</script>
```

I expected this to fire off the one ajax, then once all the details were changed on the form with the like/unlike function it would then be able to fire off the other ajax.

But I actually got one click fires off the one ajax, all the like buttons are activated, and I can't click it again.

Comment: I would stripe out the forms, add `data-types` for their ids, and communicate a toggle of like and unlike via `ajax` which response would change their URL target

Comment: @DiogoSanto Interesting, I'm not 100% sure what data-types you mean. PHP data-types, Ajax dataType, etc? I see what you mean by toggle, just not sure if it will work in the instance. Do you have an example?

Comment: Maybe [HTML data-types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*)?

Comment: Apologies, I meant the HTML data-types. So you could have `<img data-id="<img id>"` and build your JS application to handle the clicks and change their target url depending on their status change. This could deal with each image independently and avoid you using forms. Also, dpeending of how many users you expect your application to have, it might be worth it to consider queuing the changes into redis instead of instantly communicate with the database. As many requests per second can slow down your application while if you queue them, it makes things faster and more reliable for you

Comment: I do not have an example I can share with you as of this moment, only building one! If I have time and no answer was provided yet I will do one :)

Comment: @DiogoSanto Ah ok! I'm going to do some research on data-id, as I've never used this before. If you do get to do an example, that would be amazing!